# Is there a statistics module for Python 2.7?

Tags: python, numpy

Is there a statistics module (e.g. for population standard deviation) in Python 2.7?

I found this link for Python3, and would find it very useful to use....

https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html

I did find the scipy and numpy stats modules that could make standard deviation, but this is always on the axis of an array. What I want is to be able calculate the standard deviation for example, by passing the numbers and not having to rely on myself for typing the correct mathematical equation.

So for example, in python 3 it looks like I could do this:

```
 pstdev([1.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.75, 3.25, 4.75]) 
 0.986893273527251
```

Okay, so I realized that you can do more in numpy than I thought. For example, with `a` an array, I can do:

```
numpy.std(a[0,1:9])
```

However, what I would like to do is take different parts from a numpy array as input (not just one slice).

So for example, on row 0 I want to take the numbers 1 to 8 and on row 2 I want the numbers 1:3. So I wonder how to take these different slices from different locations and put then into the function. Can I somehow combine two or more slices into one expression and use that as the array-like input that is required for the numpy.std function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not built in, but **[NumPy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/index.html)** is very popular.

Here's what's available for stddev:

- http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.std.html

Example use:

```
>>> import numpy
>>> a=numpy.array([1.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.75, 3.25, 4.75])
>>> numpy.std(a)
0.98689327352725098
```

Followup question still not really clear, but is this what you're looking for?

```
>>> b=numpy.array([[1.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.75, 3.25, 4.75], [10,20,30,40,50,60]])
>>> b
array([[  1.5 ,   2.5 ,   2.5 ,   2.75,   3.25,   4.75],
       [ 10.  ,  20.  ,  30.  ,  40.  ,  50.  ,  60.  ]])
>>> c = b[0][:4]
>>> c
array([ 1.5 ,  2.5 ,  2.5 ,  2.75])
>>> d = b[1][2:5]
>>> d
array([ 30.,  40.,  50.])
>>> e = numpy.append(c, d)
>>> e
array([  1.5 ,   2.5 ,   2.5 ,   2.75,  30.  ,  40.  ,  50.  ])
>>> numpy.std(e)
19.404725387052988
```

Comment: yes, but that's only on the axis of an array, right?

Comment: It does exactly what you're asking.  See example code I just added.

Comment: sorry we,re running after each other, have a look at my edit, How do i make slices into one array on the fly?

Comment: @oaklander114: as presently edited (as of it looks, 3 minutes before your last comment), there's a demonstration of that given in the answer, no?

Comment: @oaklander114 What are you asking? You included an example array in your question. If you have a followup, give a specific variation using that example array to clarify what you want.  What does `a[0,1:9],a[1,1:3]` mean?

Comment: sorry for the confusion. I made another edit. I think that should be clear, but if not let me know what's not clear. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you can use scipy/numpy

also hear is the list of statistical packages for python with short descriptions

https://wiki.python.org/moin/NumericAndScientific